# How to Read * terminated dtmf digits in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I know Read command gets # terminated dtmf digits. But how can I read dtmf digits terminated by asterisk character **`"*"`**? 
For example, if I have to enter "092", i press "092*" from keypad.

Comment: Is it always a 3 digit extension?  If you must use * as a terminating digit, you could call Read to collect 1 digit in a loop.  Concatenate the digit string until you get a '*'.

Comment: extension number is not of fixed length, it can be of 3 to 6 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the behaviour, see *apps/app_read.c* in the asterisk source directory.

```
if (tmp[x-1] == '#') {
    tmp[x-1] = '\0';
    status = "OK";
    break;
}
```

Replace # with *.

You only need to recompile that module:

```
rm apps/app_read.o apps/app_read.so
make
cp -f apps/app_read.so /lib/asterisk/modules/
service asterisk restart
```

Comment: When I run make command as you suggested, all asterisk starts to recompile again. How can i ensure that only the app_read is rebuilt only?

Comment: The compiler configuration might have changed. If you let it compile once, then modify just one file, only that file (and the modules depend on it) will recompile. I guess new versions of *-dev/*-devel packages have been installed on the OS since the last full compile.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways here

1) not realible, but can work most of time. Just read one digit at time using AGI getdata or dialplan Read command.

2) create fork of app_read and change # to * in code.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `tmp[x-1] == '#'` to `tmp[x-1] == '*'` in apps/app_read.c is necessary but not enough.

You can do these steps:
1. Replace # with * in apps/app_read.c:

```
// if (tmp[x-1] == '#'){
if (tmp[x-1] == '*'){
    tmp[x-1] = '\0';
    status = "OK";
    break;
}
```

2. Replace # with * in main/app.c:

```
//res = ast_readstring_full(c, s, maxlen, to, fto, "#", audiofd, ctrlfd);
res = ast_readstring_full(c, s, maxlen, to, fto, "*", audiofd, ctrlfd);

//static const char default_acceptdtmf[] = "#";
static const char default_acceptdtmf[] = "*";

//res = ast_readstring(c, s, maxlen, to, fto, "#");
res = ast_readstring(c, s, maxlen, to, fto, "*");
```

3. Recompile asterisk:

```
sudo make clean
sudo make
sudo make install
```

I've done these steps and it worked for me.